# Is this a redundant term for a probability solution?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

> Six children are playing dodgeball. Each child has a ball. At the sound of the whistle, each child chooses another child at random to chase. What is the probability that there is at least one pair of children who are chasing each other?

This is a pretty common type of problem, and usually, the solution would go like this, where we use PIE:

- For one or more pairs, there are $\binom{6}{2}\cdot 3^4=1215$ choices.
- For two or more pairs, there are $\frac{\binom{6}{2} \binom{4}{2}}{2}=45$ choices.
- For three or more pairs, there are $\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}}{3!}=15$ choices.

Then, we do $1215-45+15=1185$ for undercounting and overcounting, and the answer is $1185/5^6$=$237/3125$. However, for the second bullet point, we are choosing three pairs even though we are only explicitly choosing two pairs, because the third one is predetermined after we choose $2$. Is this solution correct, or is the third term redundant, and the second term should be replaced with $\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}}{3!}$?

Comment: I disagree with the solution, but not for the reason that you suggest.  It seems to me that this incorrectly assumes no child in one of the pairs is chased by more than one child.

Comment: The solution assumes that more than one pair of children can be chased in the first bullet point. Then in the second bullet point, each of these double pairs are counted twice, therefore we subtract once in our running total (see right below the bullet points, first sentence). Then in the third bullet point, each of those triple pairs are counted three times by the first bullet point, and *negative* three times by the second bullet point (since we subtracted the second bullet point count in our running total), therefore we add our third bullet point count, thus we resolve our overcounting.

Comment: With the modification to the solution (*or to the interpretation of the problem*) that children within the pairs who chase each other might have additional children chasing them (*E.g. A chases B, B chases A, C chases A, D chases A, E chases A, F chases A... it is true that you have a pair of children (A and B) who are chasing each other*), the reason why your second and third terms should be different should become clearer.  In the second case we count cases like $A$ and $B$ chase each other, $C$ and $D$ chase each other, $E$ and $F$ chase $A$...

Comment: ...but in the third term we don't count that case since we require $E$ and $F$ to chase eachother, not one of the other children from one of the other pairs.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thank you!